# Magento extension pay4Later not working in Frontend

Tags: php, magento, installation

I have installed an extension but this is not working within magento Frontend. It seems to work fine in the Backend.

In my view.phtml I have added this code:

```
        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml(); //tier prices ?>


        <?php 
        //P4L CODE STARTS HERE

        foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):

        if(!(strcmp($alias,"finance_widget"))) {
            var_dump($alias);
            echo $html; 
        }
        endforeach;

        //P4L CODE ENDS HERE
        ?>
```

but the var_dump always returns:

```
    string(4) ""
```

instead of an html block.

Why is that? Probably an installation problem, permissions...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

can you provide the complete name of the extension and honestly I'm not sure you are calling that way the code to view.phtml of the product i think right?.

Best,
GrinGo.

Comment: I have solved it, it was a extension limitation which won't allow Configurable Products

Comment: Cool!, Let me know if you need anything else about magento stuff. I glad to help you. Best.